# making the following VBA code more efficient

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete rows that include any of the values specified. The below code worked in a sheet with ~200k rows but excel crashes when I try to run it in a sheet with 350k rows. How to make it more efficient?

```
    Sub MultiDelete()

    With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Range("A1").Activate 'change to suit the column containing the names
    Dim MultiDelete
    MultiDelete = Array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3") 'put as many names as you like in the array
    Dim G As Variant
    While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    G = Filter(MultiDelete, ActiveCell.Value)
    If UBound(G) <> -1 Then
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
   End If
    Wend
    With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: So I am not sure if this will solve your issue entirely, but using the built-in functions of VBA is generally significantly lower than handling it yourself. For instance, using ActiveCell.Offset will likely give a lower throughput than using a for-loop to iterate over the cells. The same will be true of activating the cell. You should be able to get and change the values without ever using that command.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is pretty much doing the most inefficient thing possible: selecting and filtering 350k rows one at a time to see if they match items in an array.

Instead, add an autofilter (or convert the range into an Excel Table/ListObject, as this has built in filters) then fire up the macro recorder, manually filter on your three terms, delete the results, clear the filter, stop the macro recorder, then go look at the code it generated.

The Macro Recorder should be your first port of call when working out how to go about something. It doesn't always generate elegant/efficient code and you'll often have to clean it up, but in this case you will go from glacial to warp speed.

Comment: thanks! I'm filtering ~40 terms. This is working better.

Comment: Cool. Please accept my answer if it solves your issue.